# Get pending cron job by name

Tags: magento2, cron

Is there any built in method in Magento 2 I can use to get scheduled cron job by name from cron_scheduler table? I want to check before adding cron job if there already exists pending(scheduled to run) cron job.

Why I need to be sure: I need to send order data to third part app. I am afraid to send it straight when user makes the order because the possibility of processing error. Also i do not know the state of that app. Second place where i need it is when I need to check that admin does not schedule too many cronjobs when he/she pushes the button in admin area.